# Get element after first slash with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Assuming a string like domain.com/aaaa

I want to use a .htaccess file to get the element after slash, in this case aaaa. and then redirect it to the domain.com/mypage/otherpage/aaaa

but if the url is domain.com/aaaa/bb or domain.com/aaaa/bb/sd
then it should not redirect i.e. it must redirect if and only if there is only 1 slash in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as **first rule** in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ /gromsoc.chetu.local/component/community/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: what is {REQUEST_FILENAME} here?

Comment: I am using it as it is but still getting same issue.

Comment: what i exactly want is whenever any user types domain.com/test
then it should redirect it to the domain.com/mypage/otherpage/test
but by using your solution it is not working it is saying 'The page isn't redirecting properly'

Comment: i have just modified my question as you can see.

Comment: This is my .htaccess file

# @package    Joomla

Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/?$ http://gromsoc.local/component/community/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Use my updated rule as **very first rule** in your .htaccess

Comment: sorry, still not working, getting same issue. I think there might be some other issue in the project. By the way thank you for the help.

Comment: That means you some other htaccess in your sub directories also